# Android decompress RAR files programmatically

Tags: android

Is there a way to decompress rar files in android 1.6 programmatically?

I've already tried JUNRAR but got some exceptions...

Here's my code, after successfully opening rar file, using junrar library:

```
FileHeader fh=null;
  while(true)
  {
   fh=rar.nextFileHeader();
   if(fh==null) return false;    
   if(fh.isEncrypted()) continue;     
   //check file

   if(!fh.isDirectory() && fh.getFileNameString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg")) 
   {
    try 
    {
      File f=new File(tmppath+covername);      //name of the destination file

      OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(f);            
      rar.extractFile(fh, stream);         //call junrar    

      stream.close();
      return true;
     } 
     catch (FileNotFoundException e1) 
     {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         return false;
     }
     catch (RarException e) 
     {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         return false;
     } 
     catch (IOException e) 
     {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         return false;
     }    
   }
```

And DDMS perspective show this exception...?

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2733): Uncaught handler: thread Thread-9 exiting due to uncaught exception

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2733): java.lang.VerifyError: de.innosystec.unrar.unpack.ppm.SubAllocator

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2733): at de.innosystec.unrar.unpack.ppm.ModelPPM.<init>(ModelPPM.java:73)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2733): at de.innosystec.unrar.unpack.Unpack.<init>(Unpack.java:43)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2733): at de.innosystec.unrar.Archive.doExtractFile(Archive.java:456)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2733): at de.innosystec.unrar.Archive.extractFile(Archive.java:440)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2733): at com.pmc.myRar.unrarCover(myRar.java:164)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2733): at com.pmc.myDataBase.addRar(myDataBase.java:541)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2733): at com.pmc.libraryActivity.addtoDB(libraryActivity.java:306)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2733): at com.pmc.libraryActivity$2.run(libraryActivity.java:240)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2733): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1060)
```

Thanks,
pmc

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your exceptions. There is nothing built into Android for RAR files, so you will need to find some third-party JAR for it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've edited my original post to include the code and the exception.

Answer (score 4):

You got a java.lang.Verify error, which are quite difficult to pinpoint. Is there a source code of that library to recompile it yourself? It may be that the library was compiled using a different version of another jar.

As workarounds:

There's a C library here: http://www.unrarlib.org/download.html that has a link to a JNI interface

Another (very easy) alternative is to use `Runtime.exec()` with this executable: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1015814

Comment: Thank you! I'll try your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JUNRAR library, you will meet "Out of memory" bug when you decompress a large rar file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use src,  change the function "doExtractFile" of  archive.java 
add code
            dataIO.endpack();
            unpack=null;

example

private void doExtractFile(FileHeader hd, OutputStream os)

```
        throws RarException, IOException {
    dataIO.init(os);
    dataIO.init(hd);
    dataIO.setUnpFileCRC(this.isOldFormat() ? 0 : 0xffFFffFF);
    if (unpack == null) {
        unpack = new Unpack(dataIO);
    }
    if (!hd.isSolid()) {
        unpack.init(null);
    }
    unpack.setDestSize(hd.getFullUnpackSize());
    try {
        unpack.doUnpack(hd.getUnpVersion(), hd.isSolid());
        // Verify file CRC
        hd = dataIO.getSubHeader();
        long actualCRC = hd.isSplitAfter() ? ~dataIO.getPackedCRC()
                : ~dataIO.getUnpFileCRC();
        int expectedCRC = hd.getFileCRC();
        if (actualCRC != expectedCRC) {
            throw new RarException(RarExceptionType.crcError);
            // System.out.println(hd.isEncrypted());
        }

        dataIO.endpack();//add yzd
        unpack=null;// add yzd

    } catch (Exception e) {
        unpack.cleanUp();
        if (e instanceof RarException) {
            // throw new RarException((RarException)e);
            throw (RarException) e;
        } else {
            throw new RarException(e);
        }
    }
}
```